# Remove everything before and after URL - regex find and replace notepad++

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

i have a list of url's that i want to save but they are surrounded by junk

Example:

> proxy - bla bla bla **http://demo.elefanteinstaller.com/smf/index.php?topic=39.new#new**  Result: using proxy 213.77.18.201:80; chosen nickname "#ZKGSLAW[XXXIFXXXQXXX]"; captcha recognized; registered (100%); profile edited; logged in; nofollow is found; success; >BB-code not working;

How can i make in notepad++ using the find and replace that i will save only what is starting with http:// and ends with space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep it simple:

Find what: `.* (http://.*?) .*`

Replace with: `\1`

Answer (score -1):

Also if you have access to MS Word switch to a fixed font like courier new or console (lines things up better) Then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and click and drag like you would to highlight something on the desktop. Works nicely for smaller lists.

Comment: I would assume the list is quite large and the OP wants it to be done programmatically. This is a programming forum after all.